# Cordova - Zip files and folders on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using Cordova to create a mobile application on iOS. I want to upload multiple files to server but instead of sending them one after another. I want to compress these files into one '.zip' file and upload it to server.

I searched for a Cordova plugin, but I found only these plugins that doesn't solve my problem:

- [Icenium/cordova-plugin-zip](https://github.com/Icenium/cordova-plugin-zip) to zip and unzip files on iOS but there is no documentation or example about how using it.
- [jjdltc/jjdltc-cordova-plugin-zip](https://github.com/jjdltc/jjdltc-cordova-plugin-zip) to zip and unzip files on Android platform only.

Please, help me to find a plugin that zip files and folders on iOS, or give me an example about using the first plugin.

Answer (score 4):

We have managed to unzip, modify and zip back files using the [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html) javascript API and the [cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file). It should also work to create a zip from scratch. There isn't a real need to use native code for the zipping action (although it is most likely faster), only to read the files to zip and write the zip file. Hence, it is fine to use a javascript API that wasn't designed for cordova in particular.

**Process**
If you want to try the JSZip + file plugin method, here is a quick outline of how we worked with it :

1. We use the file plugin to read files as binary. If you are lucky enough to have only text files, you could read as text too, but it's less flexible that way. Note that to read the files, you will need to obtain the `File` object from their `FileEntry` which will require navigating in the file system using `DirectoryEntry`s. If you aren't familiar with the file plugin, take a look at its documentation to do this step.
2. We create a JSZip object.
3. Manipulate the JSZip object as you want it. You can create folders within the zip, add files, remove some, modify some content. As you see fit. Their documentation gives simple and good examples.
4. Generate the zip binary content using the JSZip `JSZip#generate()` method, specifying the type. If you want to create an actual file with it, we noticed that string and arraybuffer could be written with the file plugin's write method (after creating the file) without code to convert it on iOS, but not uint8array (and we didn't try the other generation types).
5. Treat the binary as you wish. It is the same as if you had read the binary of an actual zip.

PS: The file plugin has some outdated documentation on cordova.apache.org. While the examples in it can be useful, be aware that some of those are not valid anymore. For instance, `resolveLocalFileSystemURI()` is now `resolveLocalFileSystemURL()`.

Comment: +1 for deprecated method( e.g.  resolveLocalFileSystemURI()).I'm quite familiar with file plugin and for this reason i just know